# Matplotlib speed up saving plots to disk

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, save

I want to create an animation from roughly 250 individual frames, showing data plotted as 2D images in a figure with 4 x 11 subpanels. The data represent power spectra of velocity as a function of temporal frequency and latitude. However, each frame takes about 4 seconds to create and save, including run-time computation of the data. In the non-interactive plotting mode, I use 'agg' as the backend to avoid time spent for interactivity plotting features.

The speed bottleneck here is not the computation of the data to plot, but saving the plots to disk. Example run-times for random data (see code below) and only 5 frames without saving the plots are sth. like 5 seconds, with saving the plots 17-19 seconds. For the actual data I use, there are some more plot artists to be drawn (text on panels, an additional line plot etc.), but the script execution time is quite similar. **For the about 250 frames in total, this indicates roughly 900 seconds, thus 15 minutes to compute the data and then save the plots. However, since I likely want to generate similar frames several times or with slightly different data, it would be good to decrease this script execution time.**

A (hopefully) reproducible code, using random data, but with data sizes equal to the actual data I use, is given below. An example frame (the first one generated by the code) can also be found below. In the code, the function `create_fig()` generates a figure with subpanels containing dummy data and in the `for`-loop over the different frames, only the data in the subpanels is replaced.

**Is there a way to speed-up saving the plots into the png files?** Any help is much appreciated!

```
# import packages
import numpy as np
import time

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path_plots_out = '/home/proxauf'

# set up grids
nt, nlat, nlon = 3328, 24, 48
dlat = 7.5
lats = np.linspace(-90,90-dlat,nlat)

dt = 98191.08

nu = (-1) * np.fft.fftfreq(nt, dt) * 10 ** 9
nnu = len(nu)

nu_fftshift = np.fft.fftshift(nu)
dnu_fftshift = nu_fftshift[1] - nu_fftshift[0]

nu_lims = [-500, 500]
ind_nu_xlims = np.where(np.logical_and(nu_fftshift >= nu_lims[0], nu_fftshift <= nu_lims[1]))[0]
ext_box_nu_lat = [nu_fftshift[ind_nu_xlims][0] - dnu_fftshift / 2, nu_fftshift[ind_nu_xlims][-1] + dnu_fftshift / 2, lats[0] - dlat / 2.0, lats[-1] + dlat / 2.0]
nnu_cut = len(ind_nu_xlims)

plt.ioff()
if plt.rcParams['interactive']:
    mpl.use('Qt5Agg')
else:
    mpl.use('agg')

# plotting function
def create_fig():
    
    data_xlabels = np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype='U30')
    data_xlabels[-1, :] = r'Frequency [nHz]'
    data_xticks = np.array([[np.linspace(-300, 300, 3)] * ncols] * nrows)
    data_xticks_minor = np.array([[np.linspace(-500, 500, 21)] * ncols] * nrows)
    data_xlims = np.array([[(-500, 500)] * ncols] * nrows)
    data_ylabels = np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype='U30')
    data_ylabels[:, 0] = r'Latitude [deg]'
    data_yticks = np.array([[np.linspace(-90, 90, 7)] * ncols] * nrows)
    data_yticks_minor = np.array([[np.linspace(-90, 90, 25)] * ncols] * nrows)
    data_ylims = np.array([[(-90, 90)] * ncols] * nrows)

    plot_xticks = np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype=bool)
    plot_xticks[-1, :] = True
    plot_yticks = np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype=bool)
    plot_yticks[:, 0] = True
    
    fig_left, fig_right, fig_bottom, fig_top, fig_hspace, fig_wspace = (0.04, 0.95, 0.06, 0.90, 0.1, 0.1)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=figsize)
    data_list = []
    
    for i in range(nrows):
        data_list_temp = []
        for j in range(ncols):
            ax = axes[i, j]
            im = ax.imshow(np.zeros((nnu_cut, nlat)).T, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', aspect='auto', cmap='binary', extent=ext_box_nu_lat)
            im.set_clim(0,1e4)
            ax.set_xlabel(data_xlabels[i, j])
            ax.set_ylabel(data_ylabels[i, j])
            ax.set_xlim(data_xlims[i, j])
            ax.set_ylim(data_ylims[i, j])
            ax.set_xticks(data_xticks[i, j])
            ax.set_xticks(data_xticks_minor[i, j], minor=True)
            ax.set_yticks(data_yticks[i, j])
            ax.set_yticks(data_yticks_minor[i, j], minor=True)
            if not plot_xticks[i, j]:
                ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
            if not plot_yticks[i, j]:
                ax.tick_params(labelleft=False)
            data_list_temp.append(im)
        data_list.append(data_list_temp)
    
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=fig_left, right=fig_right, bottom=fig_bottom, top=fig_top, hspace=fig_hspace, wspace=fig_wspace)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ax1 = axes[0, -1]
    ax2 = axes[-1, -1]
    top = ax1.get_position().y1
    bottom = ax2.get_position().y0
    right = ax2.get_position().x1
    cbar_pad = 0.01
    cbar_width = 0.01
    cbar_height = top - bottom
    cax = fig.add_axes([right + cbar_pad, bottom, cbar_width, cbar_height])
    cbar = plt.colorbar(data_list[-1][-1], ax=axes[-1, -1], cax=cax)
    
    return fig, axes, data_list

nrows = 4
ncols = 11
figsize = (16.5, 8)

# create figure with empty subpanels
fig, axes, data_list = create_fig()

# generate some data
np.random.seed(100)
data1 = np.random.rand(nt,nlat,nlon)
data2 = np.random.rand(nt,nlat,nlon)
data3 = np.random.rand(nt,nlat,nlon)
data4 = np.random.rand(nt,nlat,nlon)

wsize = nt // 4
data1_temp = np.zeros((nt, nlat, nlon))
data2_temp = np.zeros((nt, nlat, nlon))
data3_temp = np.zeros((nt, nlat, nlon))
data4_temp = np.zeros((nt, nlat, nlon))
data1_temp[:wsize,:,:] = data1[:wsize,:,:]
data2_temp[:wsize,:,:] = data2[:wsize,:,:]
data3_temp[:wsize,:,:] = data3[:wsize,:,:]
data4_temp[:wsize,:,:] = data4[:wsize,:,:]

frame_cad = 10
# do not activate, else program will take about 15-20 minutes to finish
# frame_inds = range(0, nt - wsize + 1, frame_cad)
frame_inds = range(0, 50, frame_cad)
t0 = time.time()
for c, i in enumerate(frame_inds):
    print(c)
    if i >= 1:
        # fill in data for the next frame
        data1_temp[i-frame_cad:i] = 0.0
        data1_temp[i+wsize- 1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad] = data1[i+wsize-1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad,:,:]
        data2_temp[i-frame_cad:i] = 0.0
        data2_temp[i+wsize- 1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad] = data2[i+wsize-1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad,:,:]
        data3_temp[i-frame_cad:i] = 0.0
        data3_temp[i+wsize- 1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad] = data3[i+wsize-1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad,:,:]
        data4_temp[i-frame_cad:i] = 0.0
        data4_temp[i+wsize- 1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad] = data4[i+wsize-1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad,:,:]
    # compute power spectrum
    pu1_temp = np.abs(np.fft.fftn(data1_temp, axes=(0, 2))) ** 2
    pu2_temp = np.abs(np.fft.fftn(data2_temp, axes=(0, 2))) ** 2
    pu3_temp = np.abs(np.fft.fftn(data3_temp, axes=(0, 2))) ** 2
    pu4_temp = np.abs(np.fft.fftn(data4_temp, axes=(0, 2))) ** 2
    pu_temp_list = [pu1_temp, pu2_temp, pu3_temp, pu4_temp]
    # update data in subpanels
    for s in range(nrows):
        for j in range(ncols):
            data_list[s][j].set_data(np.fft.fftshift(pu_temp_list[s][:,:,j], axes=(0,))[ind_nu_xlims].T)
    # save figure
    fig.savefig('%s/stackoverflow_test/frame_%04d.png' % (path_plots_out, c))
plt.close()
print(time.time() - t0)
```

[image: First frame generated by example code]

**Update**: Modified code blocks given below (no minor ticks, `pyfftw` instead of `numpy`, faster absolute-square computation; note: `data_list` return argument from `create_fig()` renamed to `plot_data_list`) yield running times of about 6s for 5 frames. The biggest speed boost comes from deactivating minor ticks (as mentioned in [Jody Klymak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66124971/5269892)).

```
# use np.take_along_axis() with sorting indices instead of np.fft.fftshift() later, gives a slight (not too much!) speed boost
ind_nu_xlims = np.where(np.logical_and(nu >= nu_lims[0], nu <= nu_lims[1]))[0]
ind_nu_sort = np.argsort(nu[ind_nu_xlims])
nu_sort = np.take_along_axis(nu[ind_nu_xlims],ind_nu_sort,axis=0)
ext_box_nu_lat = [nu_sort[0] + dnu_fftshift / 2, nu_sort[-1] - dnu_fftshift / 2, lats[0] - dlat / 2.0, lats[-1] + dlat / 2.0]
    
# plotting function
def create_fig():
    
            # deactivating ticks massively (!) boosts plotting performance
            # ax.set_xticks(data_xticks_minor[i, j], minor=True)
            # ax.set_yticks(data_yticks_minor[i, j], minor=True)

data_list = [data1, data2, data3, data4]

# wisdom makes FFTs much faster using pyfftw than using numpy
# enable cache and set cache memory-keeping time sufficiently large
# this depends on the computation time between FFT calls
pyfftw.interfaces.cache.enable()
pyfftw.interfaces.cache.set_keepalive_time(5)

for c, i in enumerate(frame_inds):
    print(c)
    data_temp_list = [data1_temp, data2_temp, data3_temp, data4_temp]
    pu_temp_list = []
    for j, data_temp in enumerate(data_temp_list):
        if i >= 1:
            # fill in data for the next frame
            data_temp[i-frame_cad:i] = 0.0
            data_temp[i+wsize-1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad] = data_list[j][i+wsize-1:i+wsize-1+frame_cad,:,:]
        # compute Fourier transform via pyfftw; wisdom makes FFTs much faster using pyfftw than using numpy
        pu_temp = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fftn(data_temp, axes=(0, 2), threads=-1)
        # compute absolute-square using np.real(x * np.conj(x));
        # about same speed as np.real(x) * np.imag(x);
        # faster than np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ijk',x,np.conj(x));
        # also faster than np.abs(x)**2 since np.abs(x)**2 first takes square-root, then squares again
        pu_temp = np.real(pu_temp*np.conj(pu_temp))
        pu_temp_list.append(pu_temp)
    # update data in subpanels
    for s in range(nrows):
        for j in range(ncols):
            # use np.take_along_axis() with sorting indices instead of np.fft.fftshift(), gives a slight (not too much!) speed boost
            plot_data_list[s][j].set_data(np.take_along_axis(pu_temp_list[s][ind_nu_xlims,:,j], ind_nu_sort[:,None], axis=0).T)
    # save figure
    fig.savefig('%s/stackoverflow_test/frame_%04d.png' % (path_plots_out, c))
plt.close()
print(time.time() - t0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if that is exactly what you want the plot to look like, then I think you are doing the fastest that you can do.  I get 15 s for 5 figures, and get 5 s for not saving.

Believe it or not, the easy way to make it faster is to drop your minor ticks.  If I comment those lines out I get 8 s, for a 70% speed up.  Ticks are really expensive in matplotlib.  Given your minor ticks are tiny, I'd suggest that as an easy optimization.

Comment: 70% is indeed a massive boost. How comes saving the minor ticks on the plot takes so much time, especially given that matplotlib does not need to choose the tick locations by itself?

Comment: It just a known inefficiency.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5665

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some tips, but can be not a solution:

- You are doing the rigth thing to run over the matrix, but check if can maximize the cache transposing your matrix (when you have a very tall and narrow case)
- Have your heard about of sparse-matrix  or matrix compressing techniques?
- do the stuff that you need to do when i<1 outside of the for loop - you will save 1 comparison if you take out that
- can you use parallel computation? like Omp for python?

Comment: I am not sure I follow all your points. ad (1): does this affect the plotting (I don't know)? ad (2): yes, but I have not used sparse matrices yet; also I am not sure this is a case for a sparse matrix, all elements are different from zero. ad (3): the case i  = 0 can be done outside the for-loop, then the if statement can be removed, but I don't think the if causes the large running time; ad (4): I guess parallelization is possible, but for most cases typically I do not need it (and thus do not use it); Do you have any tips directly related to speed-up saving the plot? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, try to save as raw,  you will save some time also .   `fig.savefig( , format='raw', )`